# Fortigate VPN can't reach site

Tags: vpn, routing, ipsec, pptp, fortigate

I've two Fortigate's here and I use one of them for each site.

Site A                                                                               Site B
192.168.2.0/24      <---------- VPN -------->                       192.168.10.0/24

The employees connect via PPTP to Site A and can just access this site, but not site b.

The Ipsec tunnel between site a and site b is working fine and I'm also able to establish a VPN connection from any PPTP client to site A, but I can't reach Site B.

```
config firewall policy
    edit 5
        set srcintf "internal"
        set dstintf "wan1"
            set srcaddr "Local_LAN"
            set dstaddr "Remote_LAN"
        set action ipsec
        set schedule "always"
            set service "ANY"
        set inbound enable
        set outbound enable
        set vpntunnel "tunnel"
    next
    edit 1
        set srcintf "internal"
        set dstintf "wan1"
            set srcaddr "all"
            set dstaddr "all"
        set action accept
        set schedule "always"
            set service "ANY"
        set nat enable
    next

    edit 50
        set srcintf "wan1"
        set dstintf "internal"
            set srcaddr "PPTP"
            set dstaddr "all"
        set action accept
        set schedule "always"
            set service "ANY"
        set nat enable
    next
    edit 4
        set srcintf "wan1"
        set dstintf "wan1"
            set srcaddr "PPTP"
            set dstaddr "all"
        set action accept
        set schedule "always"
            set service "ANY"
        set nat enable
    next
end
```

Does anyone know which policy need to set, so that I can reach it? Thanks

Update:

192.168.2.1(Site a router) to 192.168.10.1(site b router) traceroute

```
traceroute to 192.168.10.1 (192.168.10.1), 32 hops max, 72 byte packets
 1  192.168.10.1  33.596 ms  33.415 ms  32.957 ms
```

PPTP client to site b router traceroute

```
traceroute to 192.168.10.1 (192.168.10.1), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.2.160 (192.168.2.160)  37.521 ms  33.914 ms  33.654 ms
 2  h254.s98.ts.hinet.net (168.95.98.254)  58.420 ms  50.837 ms  49.903 ms
 3  tp-s2-c6r11.router.hinet.net (168.95.82.46)  49.852 ms  50.701 ms  51.416 ms
 4  tpdt-3011.hinet.net (220.128.3.114)  54.643 ms  56.940 ms  58.699 ms
 5  tpdb-3101.hinet.net (220.128.14.241)  51.098 ms  52.266 ms  50.028 ms
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
```

Comment: Beyond Firewall policies, it could be a routing issue. Have you checked this ?

Comment: @user2196728 the fortigate does actually a policy based routing. It seems to be something with the routing, but I'm unsure how to fix it.

Comment: Provide policy route config, it may help

Comment: does `Local_LAN` object include the `PPTP` object?